# Wait-Free implementation of an incremental counter

Tags: algorithms

I know the theoretical difference between lock-free and wait-free algorithms, but it's a little hard to me to figure out how do they differ in implementation (code). In particular, i would like to know how would the implementation (code) of a counter be. 
Thanks

Comment: This [paper](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/papers/podc2009-jacm.pdf) contains a wait-free algorithm for counters.

Comment: I think what you want is an example of a lock-free algorithm which isn't wait-free.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4211180/21508463

Answer (score 0):

The lock free implementation will be Compare and Swap(CAS) on the counter, inside an indefinite while loop.Let's call it the increment method.The wait free version will have a help method and an announce method.The while loop will run for a fixed number of times, if the CAS does not succeed in these tries, the thread will "announce" for help by writing in it's id to a shared data structure.As soon as thread enters the increment(),it will first "help" all the operations that have been announced.
PS:In my implementation,the counter is a structure consisting of integer value, thread id and other information.